# How do I add the Bootstrap Landkit to a rails application using the asset pipeline? (my javascript seems not to link correctly)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

Good morning all.
So there you have it, for a web application project, my team and I bought the Boostrap [Landkit](https://landkit.goodthemes.co/index.html), which we can, according to the kit's website, link to a rails application.

Only here, the architecture of the folder is very different from that of a rails application (it is adapted to Gulp if I'm not saying nonsense). To test the theme, I tried to reproduce one of their demo page identically by copying and pasting the html code of this page provided in the kit.

As each css and javascript file is called with a relative link directly in the html page, I placed these different files in the asset-pipeline ("vendor / assets / javascripts" and "vendor / assets / stylesheets"). I then require all of these files in my manifest files ("app / assets / javascripts / application.js" and "app / assets / stylesheets / application.css.scss").
I also put the links `<% = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'%>` and `<% = javascript_include_tag 'application '%>` `in my" application.html.erb "file to finalize the connection.
The css seems to work normally, however, some javascript animations seem buggy, in particular the animations of the navbar and the cards. Still, I seem to have correctly placed all the js files called in my html page in the asset-pipeline, so a little help would be welcome ^^ !

All files mentioned in the links above are added in "vendor / assets / javascripts" and "vendor / assets / stylesheets". I really don't know what to do.

Thanks for your time, and sorry for the too long explanation, but I have no idea where the problem lies, as no console errors appear when I run my server.

Here is the structure of the downloaded folder:

```
   ├──  dist - Generated production files 

   ├──  node_modules - Directory where npm installs dependencies. 

   ├──  src

              ├──  assets

              |                     ├──  css - Compiled CSS 
              |                     ├──  fonts - HK Grotesk Pro font 
              |                     ├──  img - Image assets
              |                     ├──  js - Javascript source
              |                     ├──  libs - Third party plugins 
              |                     |___  scss - SCSS source for theme 
              ├──  docs - Documentation 
              |____  partials - HTML partials 
   ├──  gulpfile.js - All the build commands  
   ├──  package.json - List of dependencies and npm information 
   |__  .gitignore - Hide all unnecessary files from Git
```

Here is the content of my "application.css.scss" :

```
 *= require feather.css
 *= require jquery.fancybox.min.css
 *= require aos.css
 *= require choices.min.css
 *= require flickity-fade.css
 *= require flickity.min.css
 *= require vs2015.css
 *= require jarallax.css
 *= require quill.core.css
 *= require bootstrap.min.css
 *= require theme.min.css
 */
```

Here is the content of "application.js" :

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require popper
//= require tether
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.min.js
//= require jquery.fancybox.min.js
//= require bootstrap.bundle.min.js
//= require aos.js
//= require navbar.js
//= require choices.min.js
//= require countUp.min.js
//= require dropzone.min.js
//= require flickity.pkgd.min.js
//= require flickity-fade.js
//= require highlight.pack.min.js
//= require imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js
//= require isotope.pkgd.min.js
//= require jarallax.min.js
//= require jarallax-video.min.js
//= require jarallax-element.min.js
//= require quill.min.js
//= require smooth-scroll.min.js
//= require typed.min.js
//= require theme.min.js
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require bootstrap
```

Here are the initial links in my the html code of the page :

```
    <!-- Libs CSS > 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/fonts/Feather/feather.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/aos/dist/aos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/choices.js/public/assets/styles/choices.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/flickity-fade/flickity-fade.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/flickity/dist/flickity.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/highlightjs/styles/vs2015.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/jarallax/dist/jarallax.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/libs/quill/dist/quill.core.css" />

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/theme.min.css">
    
     <!-- Libs JS -->
    <script src="./assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/aos/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/choices.js/public/assets/scripts/choices.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/countup.js/dist/countUp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/flickity/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/flickity-fade/flickity-fade.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/highlightjs/highlight.pack.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/jarallax/dist/jarallax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/jarallax/dist/jarallax-video.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/jarallax/dist/jarallax-element.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/quill/dist/quill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/smooth-scroll/dist/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/libs/typed.js/lib/typed.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme JS -->
    <script src="./assets/js/theme.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my "application.html.erb" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>TestTheme</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   

  </head>

  <body>
      <!-- Map -->
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <%= yield %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
      
</html>
```